# Random variables with all moments. Is this statement true?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, probability, functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a random variable such thta $X\neq 0$, $P$-a.s. Then

$$X\in \bigcap_{p\geq 1} L^p(\Omega) \iff \frac{1}{X} \bigcap_{p\geq 1} L^p(\Omega).$$

In other words, is the space $\bigcap_{p\geq 1} L^p(\Omega)$ an algebra which is closed under inversion?

I have the feeling that, at least, $\Leftarrow$ is true (using Jensen's inequality with $g(x)=\frac{1}{x^p}$).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is false. Consider the probability space $([0,1], \lambda)$ where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure. Now let

$$X(w) =
\begin{cases}
w                         & \text {if $w \neq0$} \\
1   & \text{otherwise} \\
\end{cases} $$

By the definition, $X \leq 1$ this implies $X$ belongs to all the $L^p$'s you requested. But $\frac{1}{X} \notin L^1$. This example proves that the inverse is false, once you can trivially put $\frac{1}{X}$ like above. Then $X \notin L^1$.

Jensen's inequality doesn't help in this case because the functions involved are convex, then you get just a lower bound to the $L^p$-norm of the random variables.